# The apps that I downloaded have broken and weird square titlebars

Tags: snap, flatpak, titlebar

[image]I downloaded Krita (flatpak) and its titlebar was square. When I maximized it I couldn't move certain parts of the titlebar. This also happened in VLC (snap).

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Are any other apps affected?

Comment: idk how to add screenshots on this website but no default apps that are installed with ubuntu is not affected, the apps that i install are affected

Comment: You can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1484507/edit) to upload the screenshot

Comment: ty i did it, i uninstalled krita and vlc and tried gimp (apt) i put the screenshot

Comment: Are you using the default system theme?

Comment: no but i had this exact problem when i used the default system theme

Answer (score 3):

Snap and Flatpak apps often don't follow your system theme. Unless you need the very latest version of these apps for any specific reason, the workaround is to use the APT version of these apps (which consume less storage space, integrate with other apps easily, and are often faster to launch).

Remove the flatpak and snap apps. Open a terminal, and enter the following commands.

```
sudo snap remove vlc
flatpak remove org.kde.krita
```

Then, install the APT versions

```
sudo apt install vlc krita
```

Comment: its still the same, i uninstalled them and then installed them as apt as you said but i still have the same problem